# Is there a way to use a command line tool to view the JavaScript interpreted source of a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, curl

Is there a command line tool that allows you to get the text of the JavaScript interpreted source of a web page similar to how you can see the interpreted code in FireBug on FireFox?

I would like to use CURL or similar tool to request a web page. The catch is I would like to view how the code has been modified by JavaScript. For instance if the dom has been changed or an element has been modified, I would like to see the modified version. I know FireBug does this for FireFox, but I am looking for a way to script the process.

Comment: You would need a whole browser engine that could both digest the page to create the DOM and run the javascript and then interrogate the DOM.

Comment: I wonder if any of the good :) browsers have a command-line API for just such a purpose. How does FireBug do it?

Comment: I am automating some web testing, and I need to do some tests based on the HTML that is presented to the user after JavaScript has manipulated it.

Comment: It depends how dynamic those pages are. A page could potentially change once it's loaded and bring in additional content/animations, etc. All these would change the DOM and therefore your results. A solution would need to make sure it didn't catch the DOM mid-rewrite too

Comment: Why curl? There are several frameworks that let you use real browsers (e.g., Selenium and similar), headless browsers, and so on.

Comment: Per the original question. CURL isn't a requirement, I am just looking for something I can script. Do you have any recommendations or is it Selenium?

Comment: @Lee Taylor
I have been thinking about the best way to handle the mid page updates. I can't think of a way so far that is generic and will handle mid page updates. I think I'll have to write something more specific for those cases. For now I am mostly concerned with the initial page rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked in to tools like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for running the tests? Many of them support running a "headless" browser, which lets you render pages and run JS against the rendered page without having to actually run a browser. It doesn't use `curl`, but I don't see why that should be a requirement.

For instance:

```
$ phantomjs save_page.js http://example.com
```

with save_page.js:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(system.args[1], function()
{
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check it out. Per the original question. CURL isn't a requirement, I am just looking for something I can script siding toward the command line because I would like to eventually make this web based.

Comment: By "making it web based" do you mean triggering the tests from a web interface? That should be possible; my (slender) experience with PhantomJS and similar tools is that they can be used with other automated testing tools e.g. Guard, and that suggests to me that a web script should be able to trigger a test run. (Selenium, mentioned above, is another such tool; I mention PhantomJS just because it was the first to come to mind.)

Comment: "making it web based" is definitely vague, and yes I would like to run the tools from a web interface. i have steered away from the automated testing tools, because I need to create a review/test tool so a good part of the test needs to be triggered manually and reviewed by a human who "likes to see it". PhantomJS looks promising. Are there any issues with WebKit rendering, v mozilla v msie. It would be great if there was an engine that allowed you to choose.

Comment: That's a good question, but I haven't depended on PhantomJS for cross-browser validation, so I can't answer it confidently.